# understanding PVCs with missing storageClassName

Tags: kubernetes, storage, kubernetes-pvc

Trying to understanding the [spec of PVC storageClassName](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#class-1), especially this:

> However, PVCs with missing storageClassName can be updated later once default StorageClass becomes available. If the PVC gets updated it will no longer bind to PVs that have storageClassName also set to "".

My questions are:

1. PVC with storageClassName set to "" can only be bound to PVs that have storageClassName also set to "", no matter the DefaultStorageClass admission plugin is on or off, is this true?
2. With **"PVCs with missing storageClassName can be updated later once default StorageClass becomes available."**
   Who will update the PVCs, the cluster administrator or kubernetes code?
   Which attributes will be updated?
3. **"If the PVC gets updated it will no longer bind to PVs that have storageClassName also set to ""."** this seems imply that in some case PVCs with missing storageClassName can be bind to PVs that have storageClassName set to ""?

Thank you!

In my experiments, I have a cluster with DefaultStorageClass admission plugin set to "on" but no default storage class set. When I created a PVC with no storageClassName, this PVC stayed at "Pending". Later I set one of storageClassName which is "managed-nfs-storage" as default, so that "default StorageClass becomes available", this PVC was not bound automatically. Then I tried to update the PVC by adding some arbitry annotation, this PVC was not bound.